# PHP code to fetch random data from database with link

Tags: php, database, random, hyperlink, fetch

I have a project from my college. I need to make a site which will generate random data from database. But it will also need to generate a link. So that people can copy that link (as the website is generating different data, people can see the data they want by copying the URL).

I was thinking to use RAND(). But after joining stackoverlow, I see that RAND() is not a good way.

I can fetch random data using RAND() but it is not making any URL. Which is another problem too. I post this problem before. I think I shouldn't use the RAND() function.

this is the code I'm using at this moment:

```
<!--PHP code for fetching data from database-->
<?php
  $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
  if (!$con){
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  mysql_select_db("xlsx_db", $con);

  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sheet1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");

  if (!$result) {
  echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
  exit;
  }

  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
  echo "<b>Quote: </b>";
  echo $row['quote']."<br>";
  echo $row['by']."<br>";
?>
```

Anyone could please suggest me how to do that? Any kind of help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: `RAND()` is perfectly fine for a smallish database. "Not making any URL" is unclear and would benefit from code examples.

Comment: are you using custom php or some php framework?

Comment: @ceejayoz - I think the problem is that the result needs a permalink, so the query needs to be repeatable.  If the database supports a seeding function for the RNG, that might be an option.

Comment: @ceejayoz what would the problem be with a bigger DB? Just for interest

Comment: @Sean To do `ORDER BY RAND()` it has to generate a random number for each row in the table. The larger the table, the more time that's going to take. If it's a ten item table it's going to be nearly instant.

Comment: @ceejayoz Yes, but the alternative is to `SELECT *` and the shuffle the array in PHP - surely there's not much difference in terms of performance?

Comment: @Sean Those aren't the only two options. If I'm remembering correctly, Wikipedia assigns each article an indexed, random number when it's created in the database. To take you to a random article, they compute a random value via PHP and fetch the article with a databased random value closest to that PHP-generated value. Much more efficient.

Comment: @ceejayoz Ah, of course. Or you could, knowing the number of records, simply spit out a random id and select that

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is actually what you need, but:

```
<?php
$rand = true;
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    if (is_int($_GET['id'])) {
        $id = (int) $_GET['id'];
        $q = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ?';
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $q);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'i', $id);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        if (mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1) {
            $rand = false;
            // display
        }
    }
}

if ($rand) {
    $q = 'SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1';
    // run query
    $res = mysqli_fetch_array($r);
    $url = 'www.example.com/index.php?id=' . $res['id'];
}
?>
```

The prepared statements aren't ***strictly*** necessary, since we already make sure that the `$_GET['id']` value is an integer, but for the sake of completeness ;D

If you're selecting the data from multiple tables, you could have another table storing the combinations of data and then generate the url using the combination's ID as `id` parameter.

Comment: +1 But it would be better if you provided the code to connect to the db with mysqli, since his code was with mysql and show how not to have an sql injection hole in the code...

Comment: @Bun thanks! will add `mysqli` functions. But by typecasting the ID you're already preventing injection attacks

Comment: @Bun Thank you very much for the code. But facing a problem. PHP error says "Invalid index id". Could you please tell me how to solve it? I set the index in mysql on the column id. But still showing the same problem.

Comment: @Sean Very true but for the sake of OP, I would still show some prepared statements in case he needs to have text parameters :D

Comment: @ProvashShoumma ah... that'll be because the `?id=` param isn't set, set, therefore `$_GET['id']` isn't set either in `is_int($_GET['id'])`... try the edit

Comment: @Bun added prepared statements ^_^

Comment: @Sean You are such a good guy :D If I could re-upvote I would :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a permalink, you will need to create another page. It will fetch an ID (or something that is identifying the data record you have chosen randomly) and display the specific data. You link to this at your random page.

Answer (score 0):

Find a random row in your database.
Get the row's id.
Concatenate a URL with the id.
The URL should be pointing to a page that would extract the row with the id provided from the table.

Answer (score -1):

I found this the other day and thought it to be pretty comprehensive:

http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/random